# iPhone file browse and upload in my application using objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-upload, xcode6.1, file-browser

I have developing a mobile application to  Android and IPhone,

That application have file upload concept like **.txt** , **.docx** .
I Have done in Android application with on click file upload button and it will open file browser and user can choose any type of file and can upload.

So i have below questions,

1. Is it possible to save .txt ,.docx etc, file on iPhone or iPod
2. If yes mean is any file browser availble in objective c for develop an application.

3.and any way to upload file to server from iPhone.

If any one Meet this problem means please suggest me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't necessarily feel like this is a problem. For fundamental programming like this, if android can do it so can the iPhone. Your basically asking, can an iPhone be an iPhone. Yes you can save files. Yes you can make a file browser. And yes you can upload file to a server. How you do it is up to you and your standards. We aren't here to code _for_ you but we will try to help if you get stuck at a particular instance